# Как узнать количество закладок в обзорщике Chromium (Chrome) без использования расширений?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium

Собственно как узнать количество закладок в Chromium без использования сторонних дополнений? Т.е., например, с помощью средств разработчика ли или это где-то напрямую прописано. Основное же окно для управления закладками весьма скудные данные по этому вопросу выдаёт.

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
grep ' "url": ' ~/.config/opera/Bookmarks | wc -l
```

Comment: Так можно, но мне нужен способ узнать это число в само обзорщике Chromium.

Comment: тогда причем тут линукс?)

Comment: Могу предположить, что при сборке оных под разные ОС, имеются разные возможности в итоговом ПО.

Comment: внутреннее устройство одинаково